# Enhancing existing InDesign features with plugins?

Tags: pdf, plugins, export, adobe-indesign

If I wanted to add new functionality to an existing InDesign feature (say, pdf export), can I do that with a custom plugin, or would I have to make a completely new pdf export plugin altogether, first duplicating all the functionality of the existing pdf export feature, and only then adding my new functionality to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was something simple, you could have an event listener that would listen for a `beforeExport` event with InDesign's javascript. And, within the handler, you could run a script before exporting to pdf.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

doc.addEventListener('beforeExport', beforeExport, false);

function beforeExport(e) {
   alert('hey');
   // Do stuff ...
}
```

Otherwise you would probably need to go the plugin route. You can check the [InDesign SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/indesign/sdk.html) to see if there is an API for pdf export.

Comment: Thanks! What point of the pdf export process (selecting the menuitem, operating in the 'export pdf' dialog box, launching the actual export, returning to main loop) does the event beforeExport refer to?

I'm not sure if the functionality I had in mind is as simple as you described. The actual processing isn't that complex, but I would need to add a checkbox with additional options in the actual pdf export menu. I guess that would be the bottleneck, if any...

Comment: Yeah, I think the `beforeExport` handler kicks in right before the export dialog. There's an `afterExport` handler as well, but I'm not sure if that occurs after the actual export or after the dialog is confirmed.